# findAll() from Sequelize doesn't get

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with MySQL.

When I run this code:

```
usuarioService.getAll = function () {
    Usuario.findAll().then(function (users) {
        //return users;
        console.dir(users);
    });
}
```

Instead of get the user, I get:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLhmN.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIF9z.png)

Help me, please! I'm going crazy!

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sequelize is returning an array of `instance` objects in users. An `instance` object has a number of convenience methods attached to it that allow you to act on it.

If you want to get just the data with your fields as keys, use `get({plain: true})`. For example, for the first object in the array `users[0].get({plain: true})`. If you want to keep using the instances, you can just use get with the name of your field. For example, `users[0].get('nombre')`.

You should be also able to access the properties directly on the object, even if they're not being logged, such as `users[0].nombre`.

## Edit

This is not related to the original question, but your comment on another answer. Make sure you are doing things asynchronously. The code should be:

```
usuarioService.getAll = function (cb) {
    Usuario.findAll().then(function (users) {
        return cb(null, users);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        return cb(err);
    });
}
```

Then when calling this method you would do something like:

```
router.get('your_path', function(req, res, next) {
    serv.getAll(function(err, users) {
        if (err) {
            // your err handling code
        }
        // users is now a valid js array
        // could send it in res.json(users)
    });
});
```

#### or

Since Sequelize uses promises, doing this using promises would be the best way.

```
usuarioService.getAll = function () {
    return Usuario.findAll({ raw: true });
}
```

Then when calling this method you would do something like:

```
router.get('your_path', function(req, res, next) {
    serv.getAll().then(function(users) {
        res.render('usuarios/index',{
            users: users
        })
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // your error handling code here
    });
});
```

Comment: @gerchoG you could try the `{raw: true}` suggested in the other answer by @LT-. You could also just map the results `users = users.map(function(userInstance) { return userInstance.get({ plain: true})});`. Although, if you're doing something like this, I would highly recommend a library like [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) as it's much faster than native methods. You could just then do `users = _.map(users, function(userInstance) { return userInstance.get({plain: true})});`

Answer (score 7):

You are returning a user.

The first bit you see is the SQL query that Sequelize is executing for you.

The bit that says

```
dataValues: 
   { usuario_id: 1,
    ... 
   }
```

is your user. `findAll()` should give you an array with all of your users.

If you just want the dataValues returned you can just pass in `raw: true`.

```
usuarioService.getAll = function () {
    Usuario.findAll({ raw: true }).then(function (users) {
        //return users;
        console.dir(users);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But for example, in my route js I have this:
var users = serv.getAll();

 res.render('usuarios/index', {
  users: users
 });

And I get 
TypeError: /home/gercho/develop/js/voley-manager/views/usuarios/index.jade:14
   12| th 
   13| tbody
 > 14| - for user in users
   15| tr
   16| td= user.nombre
   17| td= user.apellido

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Note that any hooks you may have won't work if you use `{raw: true}`.. very unfortunate characteristic of Sequelize

Comment: If i use { raw: true } then it wont let me use where clause in the query... i just return whole database never executing where clause.

User.findAll({ where: { 'email': body.username, isActive: 'Y' } } ).then( user => {});

returns user as undefined as there was no data retrieved