# exported function returns 'undefined' when called inside app.get()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I defined a sequelize model in a file named courses.js as such:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var connection = new Sequelize( ... );
module.exports = Courses = connection.define('courses', { ... });
```

Then required it in a file called coursescontroller.js:

```
const Courses = require('../models/courses');

function find_records() {
 Courses.findAll().then(function(records) {
  return records;
 });
}

module.exports.find_records = find_records;
```

Then finally required the function in the express router file and used it as such:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var controller = require('../controllers/coursescontroller');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 var records = controller.find_records();
 console.log(records); // console shows undefined
 res.send(records); // doesn't send anything back when I make a get request
});
```

Could you please help me get the find_records() function to work properly and return the database records when called inside the get request callback function.

Comment: `find_records` doesn't return anything, there is no return statement for that function'

Comment: also ... `.then(function(records) {
  return records;
 });` is a NOP - remove it ... then you'll see there really is no return from find_records

Comment: Possible duplicate of [findAll() from Sequelize doesn't get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214221/findall-from-sequelize-doesnt-get)

Comment: thank you so much ... I used async/await instead of promises and then returned the value from the await function and it worked, but could you please explain to me why returning the value from within the .then() callback function won't work ?

Comment: because currently your function is identical to `function find_records() {
 someFunction(); }` ... the return inside the .then does not result in `find_records` returning anything ... what you could've done is `function find_records() {
return Courses.findAll(); }` - and like magic, something is returned!

Comment: as for `.then(function(records) { return records; });` being NOP - it's like creating a function `someFunction(result) { return result; }` ... why would you ever need to call such a function :p

Comment: understood, thank you again!